# Django use model field's validators for client-side validation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have some example model with field:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=30, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(300)])
```

When I create a `ModelForm` object by `modelform_factory()` function and generate html with `.as_table()` function then for this field I get something like:

```
<input type="number" name="priority" value="30" required="" id="id_priority">
```

But I would like the output to look like this:

```
<input type="number" name="priority" value="30" required="" id="id_priority" min="0" max="300">
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: From a quick look at the source code, it looks as if Django will add `min` and `max` to the form input if you create an `IntegerField` formfield with `min_value` and `max_value`, e.g. `priority = forms.IntegerField(default=30, min_value=0, max_value=300)`. However, this doesn't help in your case where you are automatically creating a form from the model.

Comment: This is definitely what I'm looking for. So, `min_value` and `max_value` can I set only through manually creating `forms.IntegerField`?

Comment: As far as I can see, the easiest approach would be to set `min_value` and `max_value` on the form field, It might be possible to subclass `models.IntegerField` and override the `formfield` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you added proper Import ?

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

priority = models.IntegerField(default=30, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(300)])
```

Comment: Yes, I used it as you see. Should this be enough? It does not work for me.

Comment: NOTE: The validators will not run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on the fields that are included in the form. Check this link for more info.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#range-fields